# linking a app from personal account to a FB Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a app id to put in my wordpress blog so i can pull in facebook comments, likes etc. The comments I would like are on a well-established facebook Page.

From looking around here I've learnt that you cannot directly add developer apps via Page accounts, only through a personal account.

So I have created the app through my personal account, got the id and its working great both ways in my WP blog...but it's obviously linked to my personal account. Where can i relink the app to the original facebook Page I mentioned in the first paragraph? Is it possible? My personal account is listed as an administrator on the Page required. I noted there is an option in the advanced options of the app to "create a page" but I'd rather not start a community page from scratch.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: add facebook and facebook-graph-api tags to your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can't link an app ID to an existing page; you can create a new page for the app in the app's advanced settings if you want, though.